# An error was reported when reading a DICOM file: Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: ''

Tags: r

An error was reported when reading a DICOM file:

```
library(moddicom)
setwd("D:/Dosiomics")
obj.geolet <- geoLet(loadXMLInCache = T)
obj.geolet$openDICOMFolder(pathToOpen="./biyanaiChangle/17666714")
#Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: ''
```

I've checked my path it's fine.
I've been looking for 3 days now and I don't know what went wrong there. Can anyone help me?